# How to signal hook is still in error state after juju debug-hooks

Tags: juju

I was fixing some stuff using juju debug-hooks. I want to go to sleep and continue fixing stuff tomorrow. How can close the tmux session in a way that juju knows the charm is still in an error state?

Strangely, when you do `exit 1`, juju thinks the problem is fixed, and continues to run all queued hooks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, there is bug in upstream (https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1415176), for the moment there is no proposed fix. I encourage you to add yourself as "affected by this bug", so developers are aware of users being bite this issue.

Best,